# Variable SQL column Default Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I would like to have a column's default value be a specified on a per session basis. The below script doesn't work, but describes how I would like to use it.  I am currently using MySQL 5.5.28, but can upgrade if necessary.

```
CREATE TABLE my_tbl (
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 data VARCHAR(45),
 date_created  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
 date_modified TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 created_by    INT DEFAULT         CUSTOM_USER_ID, 
 modified_by   INT ON UPDATE       CUSTOM_USER_ID
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- Will set created_id and modified_id=111
SET @CUSTOM_USER_ID=111;
INSERT INTO my_tbl(data) VALUES('hello');

-- Will set modified_id=222
SET @CUSTOM_USER_ID=222;
UPDATE my_tbl SET data='goodby' WHERE id=1;

-- Will keep modified_id=222
SET @CUSTOM_USER_ID=333;
UPDATE my_tbl SET data='hello again',modified_id=modified_id WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: this is impossible. Instead, you have to use an applicative layer to implement the default value. A trigger, although costly, sounds like a good candidate

Comment: @Sebas.  Thanks!  I was also thinking of a trigger.  Wasn't sure if the updating of the record within the trigger would trigger another trigger.  Thoughts?

Comment: yes it could happen. But I think in your case you would just have to change the :NEW value to the one you want (say, BEFORE INSERT happens) See this example: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0260__Trigger/Beforeinserttrigger.htm

Comment: @Sebas.  Sounds like a good idea.  You think it is very costly?  There is no insert, but only setting a variable.

Comment: yes, but every single time you'll have an insert or update on that table the trigger will fire (to not do anything if not necessary of course, but just firing it could cost a lot if you suddenly decide to insert 100000 records)

Comment: @Sebas  Please let me know why you think it is costly.

Comment: @Sebas.  Thanks, makes sense.  Records are inserted by humans, so if I have 100000 records being inserted at the same time, I have a good thing going!  My alternative is just making sure all queries manually insert the user_id, but seems like the tradeoff is not needed.

Comment: Oh, human 1x1 insertions won't be a problem. The trigger is a viable solution in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm posting an alternative:

```
delimiter $$

SET @CUSTOM_USER_ID=111;

CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger_INS BEFORE INSERT ON my_tbl FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.created_by IS NULL OR NEW.created_by = '' THEN
        SET NEW.created_by = @CUSTOM_USER_ID;
    END IF;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger_UPD BEFORE UPDATE ON my_tbl FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.modified_by IS NULL OR NEW.modified_by = '' THEN
        SET NEW.modified_by = @CUSTOM_USER_ID;
    END IF;
END$$

delimiter ;
```

[CREDITS](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0260__Trigger/Beforeinserttrigger.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  Read the following from MySQL documentation:

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column. See Section 11.3.5, “Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP”.

You can't use an expression like this to define a default value.

Comment: Bummer!  Any suggested other ways to implement?